# after thowing eror java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: db.driver method works correctly

Tags: java

after throwing eror method works correctly

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: db.driver
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
    at cinema.util.ConnectionManager.loadDriver(ConnectionManager.java:20)
    at cinema.util.ConnectionManager.<clinit>(ConnectionManager.java:15)
    at cinema.dao.FilmDao.findAll(FilmDao.java:19)
    at cinema.StartApp.main(StartApp.java:13)  
Film(id=1, name=saw, timeAndDate=2022-03-08T14:29:51.455397, ticket=100)
Film(id=2, name=saw, timeAndDate=2022-03-08T14:30:10.400193, ticket=100)
Film(id=3, name=saw, timeAndDate=2022-03-08T14:32:35.572262, ticket=100)
```

connection

```
public final class ConnectionManager {

    private static final String URL_KEY = "db.url";
    private static final String USER_KEY = "db.user";
    private static final String PASSWORD_KEY = "db.password";
    private static final String DRIVER_KEY = "db.driver";

    static {
        loadDriver();
    }

    private static void loadDriver() {
        try {
            Class.forName(DRIVER_KEY);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Connection get() {
        try {
            return DriverManager.getConnection(
                    PropertiesUtil.get(URL_KEY),
                    PropertiesUtil.get(USER_KEY),
                    PropertiesUtil.get(PASSWORD_KEY)
            );
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
db.driver=org.postgresql.Driver  
db.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/cinema  
db.user=user  
db.password=user
```

method

```
 @Override
    public List<Film> findAll() {
        List<Film> filmList = new ArrayList<>();
        try (Connection connection = ConnectionManager.get()) {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(FIND_ALL_FILMS_QUERY);
            ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                filmList.add(buildFilm(resultSet));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new DaoException(e);
        }
        return filmList;
    }
```

query

public static final String FIND_ALL_FILMS_QUERY = "select id, name, date_and_time, tickets_list from film";

the method works correctly, but throws an exception first
how to fix it?

Comment: `Class.forName(PropertiesUtil.get(DRIVER_KEY))`, not `Class.forName(DRIVER_KEY)`.

Comment: @Andy Turner
  delete it?

Comment: Deleting it is going to be equivalent to what you are doing already: it's not loading a class. If you don't need to load the class there, sure, get rid of it; but I'd ask why you thought you wanted it there in the first place.

Comment: @Andy Turner fixed by Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver"); and why did it give an error, can you explain?